# SQL Query if no records return joined records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL Server Query:

```
SELECT 
    @alloweddays as alloweddays,
    @prevalloweddays as prevalloweddays,
    ISNULL(COUNT(0),0) as useddays,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(0) > @alloweddays THEN COUNT(0) - @alloweddays ELSE 0 END as daysinadvance,
    CASE WHEN @alloweddays > COUNT(0) THEN @alloweddays - COUNT(0) ELSE 0 END as remainingdays,
    temp.prevremainingdays
FROM 
    employee_holiday_item hi
JOIN
    (SELECT 
        CASE WHEN @prevalloweddays > COUNT(0) THEN @prevalloweddays - COUNT(0) ELSE 0 END as prevremainingdays,
        hi.employeeid
     FROM 
        employee_holiday_item hi
     WHERE 
        hi.employeeid = 351
        AND hi.isactive = 1
        AND hi.date BETWEEN @prevstartperiod AND @prevendperiod
     GROUP BY 
        hi.employeeid) temp ON temp.employeeid = hi.employeeid
WHERE 
   hi.employeeid = 351
   AND hi.isactive = 1
   AND hi.date BETWEEN @startperiod AND @endperiod
GROUP BY 
   temp.prevremainingdays
```

If there are no records in the first select then no records are returned, but I would like to get at least the `JOIN` select records.

This query gets the holidays requested by an employee in the actual year. The join gets the unused days from the last period, so if the the employee has no holiday requests in the actual year I want to see at least the unused days from the last period.

I was thinking on having 2 complete separate selects and then just do `UNION ALL` but don't know if its the best way to do it.

Any clue?

Comment: Read about INNER, OUTER, LEFT and RIGHT JOIN: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16598900/2441442

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
...
FROM employee_holiday_item hi
JOIN(
SELECT
    CASE WHEN @prevalloweddays ...
```

to

```
...
FROM employee_holiday_item hi
RIGHT OUTER JOIN(
SELECT
    CASE WHEN @prevalloweddays ...
```

This is saying "take everything from the right side of `JOIN` and return it no matter what... if results are returned on the left side of the `JOIN` return them as well."